# How to update model attribute from Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method to change user status inside the it's model, is it possible to use this do something like this inside the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def confirm!
  super
  self.update_column(:status => "active")
end

end
```

I saw these two examples;

[Rails update_attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879883/rails-update-attribute)

[how to update attributes in self model rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217097/how-to-update-attributes-in-self-model-rails)

couldn't quite get which one to go with!

Comment: Those are both good solutions - could you clarify your question to state why you are confused about the two and what you want cleared up specifically?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you want any validations in the model to run. `update_attribute` will not run the validations, but `update_attributes` will.  Here are a couple of examples.

Using `update_attributes`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true

  def confirm!
    update_attributes(status: 'active')
  end
end
```

The following will return `false` and will not update the record, because not email has been set:

```
user = User.new
user.confirm! # returns false
```

Using `update_attribute`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true

  def confirm!
    update_attribute(:status, 'active')
  end
end
```

The following will update status to active regardless of whether or not email has been set:

```
user = User.new
user.confirm! # returns true
```

Comment: Ow wow, thanks, I will try this right away, thanks for thed etailed answer!

Comment: @Observer not sure if a bang(`!`) method really applies here. Please look into how these methods function in `ruby` and `Rails`. I think if you want a `confirm!` then this should `raise` on error then also create a `confirm` that does not raise but instead returns a `boolean`. Look at `save` vs `save!` for an example.